# Force Photshop to wireframe/outline view

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to force photshop  to change its display mode ?

I work with psd files that sometimes get very large(who doesn't) and at times I run out of resources(memory, processing power) on my device.

It takes ages just to nudge a group sometimes that is why I am looking for a display performance reduction to free up resources.

Is there a way to reduce the quality of the preview simmilar to Adobe Illustrator (View > Outline) [image]

Comment: Maybe some magic plugin/add on/ some trick(dirty too, maybe disable graphics or somthing) anything!

Comment: A 'wireframe' mode is only applicable to vector based drawings (where said wireframes exist as lines). PhotoShop, for the most part, is pixels. Every individual pixel has to be rendered. If you are illustrating objects that you feel should have a wireframe mode, then you are probably using the wrong software and should switch to a vector illustration product instead.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible. Photoshop has no "wireframe" mode. It's pixels or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, as [Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/21886/408) and [DA01](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21885/force-photshop-to-wireframe-outline-view#comment30356_21885) have already  mentioned, it's just not possible.

To address your problem with performance:

You can make some adjustments to Photoshop's performance by going to `Edit -> Preferences -> Performance`.

From there you can change how much RAM Photoshop is allowed to use. Bumping this up may make Photoshop fast but may slow down the rest of your machine while Photoshop is running.

You can also play with `History & Cache`

> The more cache levels you have, the slower Photoshop opens the file, but the more responsive it is while you work.
>
> <sub>Source: [helpx.adobe.com](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/optimize-performance-photoshop-cs4-cs5.html#main_Set_Performance_preferences)</sub>

There's a [great article here](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/optimize-performance-photoshop-cs4-cs5.html#main_Set_Performance_preferences) on the settings you can tweak to bring out the best performance given your hardware. They also have some [helpful tips](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/optimize-performance-photoshop-cs4-cs5.html#main_Best_practices_for_working_in_Photoshop).

At the end of the day though, performance issues will come from your computer's hardware limitations. More RAM, faster processing and disk access, as well as video cards (GPU) can all help with the performance in one way or another.